# How can I add minus/plus icons to bootstrap collpase panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using bootstrap and have collapse panels I wish to implement plus and minus icons.

I have currently done it using the code below found on stackoverflow, i can't remember the link so will edit later. It uses the code below however I have to duplicate it for each group of collapse panels as they have a unique id. Is there a way to it so it's only required once and will work on multiple on the same page?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var $active = $('#accordionthree .panel-collapse.in').prev().addClass('active');
  $active.find('.symbol').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-left"></span>');
  $('#accordionthree .panel-heading').not($active).find('.symbol').prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-left"></span>');
  $('#accordionthree').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e)
  {
    $('#accordionthree .panel-heading.active').removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    $(e.target).prev().addClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
  });
  $('#accordionthree').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e)
  {
    $(e.target).prev().removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS solution :**

```
.panel-heading a:after {
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content:"\2212";
    float: right;
    color: grey;
}
.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
    content:"\2b";
}
```

Based on  collapse example in **[Collapse accordion example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)** and using [font-awesome](https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css).

Hope this helps.

---

```css
.panel-heading a:after {
  font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content:"\2212";
  float: right;
  color: grey;
}
.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
  content:"\2b";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" 
           href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel2">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" 
           href="#collapseTwo" class="collapsed">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel3">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree"
           href="#collapseThree" class="collapsed">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```